# Swift and Sprite kit not touching properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game with Sprite Kit where the user has tap balls that pass through the screen. The balls are spawned every 1 second. However, if two balls have spawned and the user taps the first ball only the second (and any that have spawned after that) will be removed/recorded and not the one the user actually tapped.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = self.nodes(at: location).first

        if node?.name == "BALL" {
            currentScore += ballValue
            player?.removeFromParent()
        }
        else {
            gameOver()
        }
    }

}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setupTracks()
    createHUD()

    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run {
        self.createBall(forTrack: self.track)
        }, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)])))

}

func createBall(forTrack track: Int) {

    setLevel()

    player?.name = "BALL"
    player?.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    ballValue = 1

    let ballPosition = trackArray?[track].position

    player?.position = CGPoint(x: (ballPosition?.x)!, y: (ballPosition?.y)!)
    player?.position.y = (ballPosition?.y)!
    player?.zPosition = 1

    if ballDirection == "right" {
        player?.position.x = 0
        moveRight()
    }
    else {
        player?.position.x = (self.view?.frame.size.height)!
        moveLeft()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure it’s because you do:

```
player?.removeFromParent()
```

no matter which sprite is touched, but `player` is always the last sprite spawned. You’ve already assigned the node that was touched to `node`, so I think you need to do:

```
node.removeFromParent()
```

instead.